# How to put boxplots of different distribution on the same yaxis

Tags: r

I want to put these two distribution of boxplots at the same y-axis. How could I code this? 
Thanks!

```
a<- rnorm(50,0,1)
b <- rnorm(50,0,1)

par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
barplot(sort(a), main="a", ylab="",cex.main=0.9)
barplot(sort(b), main="b", ylab="",cex.main=0.9)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean two separate plots with a common scale for each y axis, or overlaid plots sharing a single y axis?

Comment: @Limey They should share the same y-axis!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the range on the y axis:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
barplot(sort(a), main="a", ylab="",cex.main=0.9, ylim = c(-1, 2))
barplot(sort(b), main="b", ylab="",cex.main=0.9, ylim = c(-1, 2))
```

Alternatively, if you want to have just **one** y-axis for both plots, you can suppress the second y-axis with `yaxt = "n"`:

```
barplot(sort(a), main="a", ylab="",cex.main=0.9, ylim = c(-1, 2))
barplot(sort(b), main="b", ylab="",cex.main=0.9, ylim = c(-1, 2), yaxt = "n")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `ggplot`:

```
library(tidyverse)
a<- rnorm(50,0,1)
b <- rnorm(50,0,1)

df <- tibble(a = a, b = b) %>% 
  pivot_longer(a:b)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = if_else(name == "b", value + 4, value), y = value, fill = name, color = name)) +
  geom_col()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

Comment: Beat me to it. :)

Comment: @Limey, thanks for your reply! But now it is mixed, they should be as separate graphs and some space between them. The same as the picture I attached but with the same y-axis

Comment: @user11916948 I see. Check updated answer. You can play with the added number in the `if_else` statement to control how much the two are separated.

Comment: Ah you mean on the same scale? Then @Chris Ruehleman's answer does the trick